# Which file does ubuntu read first after boot?

Tags: 14.04, boot, files

In what order does Ubuntu read the files from power-on until a completed startup?

Also is `upstart` something like a daemon? [I am referring to this](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) and found upstart is a daemon replacement.

> Upstart is an event-based replacement for the `/sbin/init` daemon which
>   handles starting of tasks and services during boot, stopping them
>   during shutdown and supervising them while the system is running.

[This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Other_Upstart_Commands) lists some upstart commands. In what order are they called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very complex question that is easiest answered by installing `bootchart`…

```
apt-get install bootchart
```

Now, every time when your system reboots, it will create a `.png` file in `/var/log/bootchart/` that contains not only the answer to your question, but also the time each command took, the CPU&disk utilisation, … everything you could ever ask about the boot process.

Except for the question: "Is upstart a daemon?"  I would say "yes and no" but feel free to [make up your own mind](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)…

Comment: That's a really neat tool.  Thanks for the post.

It creates a LOT of data though.  6 Meg the first time I booted.

Probably won't leave it installed but putting in the bag-o-trix.

Comment: A click on the little grey check-mark to the left of my answer turning it green would be helpful to me!  ;-)  And what I do is once every couple of months I delete all of them except the first one made during that month.  That way if something goes wrong along the line, I have historical boot charts going back a long, long way and can see what went wrong with my system exactly where!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't the asker so an upvote is all I can do :)

Comment: Ah!  **:-)**  I missed that bit!!!  ;-) (and thanks for the upvote!)

Comment: @cutteeth: is there anything wrong with my answer?  (no accept nor upvote seen from you yet)

Comment: @Fabby sorry for the delay. And thanks for the mention of bootcharts. Its awesome :)